# Loopback lb-ng (LoopBack Angular SDK command-line tool) not working

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm going through the tutorials of http://docs.strongloop.com, and I've reached http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Add+a+client+app.

Yet when I execute 'lb-ng ../server/server.js js/lb-services.js' I get an error: Cannot find module 'loopback'.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For the new version of loopback you need to install lb-ng command with this line of command

```
sudo npm install -g loopback-sdk-angular-cli
```

also try to be in the client folder make sure that you have js directory in client directory then execute these lb-ng commad

```
lb-ng ../server/server.js js/lb-services.js
```

it will work
:)

Answer (score 0):

did you `npm install` your dependencies? check and see if you have a `node_modules` dir in your project root.

Comment: Yep. I do have node_modules, and node_modules/loopback.

Comment: where are you executing 'lb-ng' from? 'lb-ng' accepts two args, thr first is the relative path to '/server/server.js' and the second is the relative path of where you want to generate the file.

Comment: did you `cd` into the `client` dir? like are you executing the command inside the client dir? `lb-ng` is relative to where you execute to the command

Comment: relevant paths: 'project/client/js', 'project/server/server.js'.
 I'm in the client dir, executing 'lb-ng ../server/server.js js/lb-services.js'.

Comment: try scaffolding a new loopback app and generating it. are you using the latest version of loopback? `npm install -g strongloop`. do you have a directory in `client` named `js`?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a newer version of node, try uninstalling node and reinstalling an **LTS** version.

```
npm uninstall -g strongloop

npm cache clear

npm install -g strongloop
```

This is how I fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

install strong loop and then run `lb-ng` command this is how i fixed this problem

Comment: May I encourage you to read the [answer] page. Here you find some help to improve your (brief) answer.